# Error de orden en consulta sqlite con Python

Tags: python, sqlite

Tengo una consulta a sqlite que me ordena unos resultados grabados desde una aplicación realizada en wxpython.
El problema es que al ordenar en "ASC" me sale primero el tiempo de 14 segundos y después el de 3, 8, 9...., parece que funciona bien, pero al tener dos cifras se ve que solo coge la primera en el orden y saca primero(erróneamente) el 14, que realmente seria el ultimo.
La consulta que ejecuto es la siguiente:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM tiempos1 INNER JOIN corredor WHERE  corredor.id = tiempos1.id_corredor ORDER BY tiempos1.tiempo ASC')
```

El resultado es el siguiente (una imagen vale mas que mil palabras):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El módulo `sqlite3` de python permite crear funciones de ordenación ([**collation**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.create_collation)).

Para tu caso, podría hacerse así:

```py
import sqlite3

def str_to_time(time: str) -> list[int]:
    return [int(x) for x in time.split(":")]

def collate_time(time1: str, time2: str):
    t1 = str_to_time(time1)
    t2 = str_to_time(time2)

    return (
        0 if t1 == t2 else
        -1 if t1 < t2 else
        1
    )

con = sqlite3.connect("data.db")
con.create_collation("time", collate_time)

cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM tiempos1 INNER JOIN corredor"
            " WHERE corredor.id = tiempos1.id_corredor"
            " ORDER BY tiempos1.tiempo COLLATE time")

for row in cur:
    print(row)

con.close()
```

Si controlas la creación de la tabla, y sólo accedes mediante tus scripts, una opción interesante sería asignar el *collation* a la columna:

```py
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE tiempos1 ("
            " ...."
            " tiempo text collate time"
            ");")
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: He probado tu código y funciona correctamente. Voy a intentar implementarlo dentro de mi modulo, no se si seré capaz ya que mi python es bastante básico. Ya comento y de nuevo muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

He implementado tu código en el modulo, y funciona todo correctamente.
El  implementar el collation en la columna no lo intentare por que la base de datos esta creada y yo solo accedo a modificarla o leerla. De todos modos es un punto interesante que no dejare de mirar para futuros proyectos.

El listado ahora luce asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De nuevo muchas gracias por tu tiempo